# System.AccessViolationException exception in C# and shell32.dll

Tags: .net, pinvoke

i write a snippet code that deletes a specified directory in SHFileOperation method.

The SHFileOperation class from a [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shfileoperation)

the flowing is my test code:

```
 var interop = new InteropSHFileOperation();
 interop.wFunc = InteropSHFileOperation.FO_Func.FO_DELETE;
 interop.pFrom = path;
 interop.fFlags.FOF_SILENT = true;
 interop.fFlags.FOF_NOERRORUI = true;
 interop.fFlags.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = true;
 return interop.Execute();
```

the above code can worked in my computer(win7,32-bit,.net 4.0),

but when running above code to my other computer(win 2008,64-bit,.net 4.0),i get the flowing error(from windows event viewer):

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Shopbots.IO.InteropSHFileOperation.SHFileOperation(SHFILEOPSTRUCT ByRef)
   at Shopbots.IO.InteropSHFileOperation.SHFileOperation(SHFILEOPSTRUCT ByRef)
   at Shopbots.IO.InteropSHFileOperation.Execute()
```

and from windows exceton dialog

```
event name : APPCRASH
Fault Module Name:  shell32.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.0.6002.18646
Fault Module Timestamp: 4fd23d65
Exception Code: c0000005
```

[update 2]

according "**Don't declare a value for the Pack size. If you omit it, the correct value is used when marshaling and a single SHFILEOPSTRUCT can be used for both 32-bit and 64-bit operation.**" from a other article:http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SHFILEOPSTRUCT.html:

change a SHFILEOPSTRUCT declare that work 32-bit and 64-bit windows operator system(because the InteropSHFileOperation class from pinvoke site that declare a SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure for 32-bit operator system)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Did you read the comments about the string needing to be double null terminated? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shfileoperation

Comment: yes,i have read.i just noticed this may be the operating system version 32 and 64 issues.i read again and notice about this :The SHFILEOPSTRUCT StructLayout attribute needs a Pack=2 (win32 - see this in the example) and Pack=8 (win64) parameter. Without it, it does not work. Of course both cannot be set for the same struct, so 2 structs are needed.

Comment: Don't pinvoke this, it is already wrapped by the .NET framework.  Use FileSystem.DeleteFile() instead.

Comment: It's a standard Win32 struct. It's aligned. Remove Pack from your declarations.

Comment: @Hans The asker is trying to delete a directory.

Comment: Connect a debugger and see what address is being accessed. Compare it to the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure generated by C# and the SHFILEOPSTRUCT defined in Win32.

Comment: Okay, then use FileSystem.DeleteDirectory().  This is an effin' painful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common failure mode for `SHFileOperation` is that the paths need to be double null-terminated. I suspect that you have forgotten to do that and if you do so an access violation is one possible outcome.

As for packing of the struct, it's a standard Win32 struct. It's not packed, it is aligned. Remove the `Pack` parameter from the `StructLayout` attribute.

I cannot understand why you would not call [`FileSystem.DeleteDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127970.aspx).